# get_users - Sort by a different meta_value than search criteria

Tags: users

I have this code and it works fine but it is not sorted.

```
    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'pw_user_status',
        'meta_value' => 'approved',
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );
```

I tried to sort the results using the below with no success...

```
$args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'pw_user_status',
                'value' => 'approved' ,
            ),
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'user_lastname',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
$users = get_users( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `'meta_key' => 'last_name'` instead of `'meta_key' => 'user_lastname'`

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'pw_user_status',
            'value' => 'approved' ,
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```